# What is the difference between dprobit and probit in stata?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, stata, probit

My boss gave me this do file but I have never worked with dprobit. I also need to interpret it, this is the result:

```
 xi: dprobit apoyado $X, robust nolog
i.fuerza          _Ifuerza_1-9        (_Ifuerza_1 for fue~a==Comando General  omitted)
note: _Ifuerza_8 != 0 predicts success perfectly
      _Ifuerza_8 dropped and 1 obs not used

note: _Ifuerza_2 dropped because of collinearity
note: _Ifuerza_9 dropped because of collinearity

Probit regression, reporting marginal effects           Number of obs =    592
                                                        Wald chi2(5)  =  33.04
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -387.38545                       Pseudo R2     = 0.0433

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         |               Robust
 apoyado |      dF/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     x-bar  [    95% C.I.   ]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
_Ifuer~3*|  -.1759987   .1586211    -1.10   0.273   .162162   -.48689  .134893
_Ifuer~4*|  -.3915721   .1314311    -2.56   0.011   .155405  -.649172 -.133972
_Ifuer~5*|  -.2404857   .1450899    -1.60   0.110   .533784  -.524857  .043885
_Ifuer~6*|   .0252801   .1673778     0.15   0.881   .087838  -.302774  .353335
_Ifuer~7*|   .0776492   .1834521     0.41   0.681   .038851   -.28191  .437209
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
  obs. P |   .5675676
 pred. P |   .5723459  (at x-bar)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(*) dF/dx is for discrete change of dummy variable from 0 to 1
    z and P>|z| correspond to the test of the underlying coefficient being 0
```

Comment: The output is very garbled, and the question, as written, is so broad and has so little detail that it is very difficult to answer.  Could you reformat the question so that it is interpretable (or use pastebin to post the output) and provide more detail about the problem / data / analysis, etc?

Comment: How far did you get in the [Stata help system](http://www.stata.com/support/documentation/)?  What aspect(s) of its explanation of these commands do you need assistance with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all else fails, check the [help file](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dprobit). First of all, it is apparently an obsolete command and Stata would prefer that you use the regular `probit` command followed by the `margins` command. The help file will also explain that the fitted model is the regular probit model, but the estimates are the estimated effect of changing the covariate by one unit on the probability of the outcome. Regular probit would give the effect on the probit-transformed probability of the outcome, which is difficult to interpret.

For example, the coefficient of `_Ifuer~3` estimates that if you go from level 1 of `fuerza` to level 3, then the probability of the outcome decreases by 0.176.

Note that you have other things going on which I can't interpret without seeing a cross-tabulation of the levels of `fuerza` and the outcome, but it appears that level 8 has no successes? There is also something going on with levels 2 and 9?

Comment: Thanks!! This helped very much. You were right, there was a problem with the data base, but I fixed it. Now there is no collineality and most of the variables are significant. As well, now I understand  how to read the results :)